# How to get "stars" back in new Picasa installation?

Tags: picasa

I had my large photo collection (~50GB) in Picasa on Windows. I've copied the entire collection (including all *picasa.ini* files) to a new partition and reinstalled Windows and Picasa on a new partition. I still have the original Picasa folder on the original partition, but it's not bootable.

**Problem:** The new Picasa installation has no *starred* photos, and I think all the captions are also gone. I thought that this information is stored in the INI files, but that seems to not be the case.

**Can I somehow restore or extract the "starred" information and the captions?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup.

For stars, copy this file from the old partition

`%localappdata%\google\Picasa2\db3\starlist.txt`

into the same folder on the new partition. This file just has a list of paths so the paths must match. You might get lucky and find your captions there as well.

Unfortunately, you might not have this folder anymore if you just kept the collection of photos.